# Assign tinymce language tags to bulleted lists (joomla4)

Tags: tinymce, multilingual, joomla4

I'm using joomla 4 in multilingual and I'm using tinyMCE editor and I configured the language parts in the plugin settings.

When I go to use the editor, I write a text, select it and assign it a language.

All marked elements have the code for example lang="it-IT" or lang="en-EN" depending on the selected language (in my case Italian or English)

Then through the css I go to hide with "display: none;" the language depending on whether they are on the Italian or English language.

Everything works fine, except for the bulleted lists, in fact when in the editor I go to assign the language to a bulleted list, the language tag is assigned only to the  tag and not to the

or  tag.

Is it possible to solve this problem?